# media conversion library/plugin preferably php

Tags: java, php

I am looking for an media conversion library that can convert and compress various media i.e both audio and video files to various formats.

Answer (score 4):

FFMPEG-PHP is a popular choice for extracting information. It doesn't re-encode files, though. http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/

But if you have an instance of FFMPEG installed on the machine, you can call [FFMPEG](http://ffmpeg.org/) via the [exec](http://www.php.net/function.exec) function in php.
Eg: `exec(’ffmpeg -i ‘.$SourcePath.’ ‘.$Destination);`

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is [ffmpeg-php](http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/) (can be used for both audio and video conversions). [Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/video/) has a few basic video conversion options as well.

Comment: FFMPEG-PHP does not do conversions. It only reads data from files.

Comment: @evilpenguin: you're absolutely correct -- my bad! Your answer to use ffmpeg through exec seems to be correct approach.

Answer (score 0):

A second option would be to use `mencoder` from the [MPlayer project](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/) (again, you'll have to call this as a command line tool). The main difference between ffmpeg and MPlayer is that the former comes with open source codecs while the latter comes with a host of codecs from all kinds of sources plus it uses ffmpeg.

So ffmpeg is a little more simple to use, MPlayer can convert between many more formats but the command line gets pretty complex.

Comment: heard a lot of good things about MEncoder, too. never used it, though.