# Python .flv media file conversion

Tags: python, flv, multimedia, bulk

I'm looking for a library similar to FFDshow to help me convert .flv to .avi format and possibly do more. I understand that I can do this via VLC player, but I'd rather do it manually with Python (and in bulk).

Similar to:
[media conversion library/plugin preferably php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233685/media-conversion-library-plugin-preferably-php)
[python automate ffmpeg conversion from upload directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123435/python-automate-ffmpeg-conversion-from-upload-directory)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ffmpeg`. You can invoke it from python, if you want to.

```
ffmpeg -i in.flv -f avi -vcodec mpeg4 -acodec libmp3lame out.avi
```

Full ducumentation for converting files with ffmpeg can be found [here](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-doc.html#SEC5).

Comment: Thanks. I love the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

[`pygst`](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/modules/gst-python.html) with the right plugins can read .flv files (and write other formats).